# replace nulo com valor anterior em oracle

Tags: oracle

pretendo fazer um replace de um valor nulo pelo ultimo valor anterior a esse nulo ou nulos.

usando LAG no casos onde tenho 2 nulos ou mais apenas faz o replace no primeiro nulo.

a COL1 é a chave, a COL2 o valor original e a COL3 o resultado esperado.

(na explicação na coluna "--", o else é tudo col2)

**RESOLVIDO**

através desta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977267/fill-null-values-with-last-non-null-amount-oracle-sql

exemplo na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pedro, utilize a parte mais abaixo **Sua Resposta** e coloque o que foi necessário para resolver este problema. Desta forma a pergunta ficará como respondida. Neste site, não se utiliza esta marcação RESOLVIDO. Veja mais detalhes no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: "Sua Resposta" ou "Responder à sua pergunta"?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quando é para você mesmo aparece diferente, tinha esquecido.